# B64 image is not displayed in angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I want to display B64 image string in angular. When i put the static image string it is displayed but when image is dynamic then it shows some problem 
Below is my component.ts code

```
      this.Socket_io = socketIo('http://192.168.0.109:3011');
      this.Socket_io.on('echo', (obj) => {

      var a = JSON.parse(obj)

      this.img = a.image_path;

      this.image_path = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,'  
      + this.img);
```

Below is my html

```
     <img [src]="image_path">
```

[Image string is being shown in html but it is not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dG9YO.png)

[B64 string coming as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjwE9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<img [src]="image_path">
```

here is stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-view-image?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: please explain your answer. (End of Review).

Comment: Sir when i am giving static B64 string then image is being displayed. But when i am getting dynamic  B64 string, the image is not displayed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src="{{'data:image/jpg;base64,' + image_path}}" />
```

Comment: Are you sure content of a.image_path (your base64 string) is correct? I used that before and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can try this
```

> ```
>     import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
>     export abstract class AppComponentBase {
>
>         sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
>     }
>         constructor(injector: Injector) {
>          this.sanitizer = injector.get(DomSanitizer);
>     }
>         sanitize(image_path: string) {
>             return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image_path);
>         }
> ```